# How to find string position within another string in C recursively?

Tags: c, string, recursion

we have an assignment to create recursive function with two string parameters, the **prototype should look like this**:

```
int instring(char* word, char* sentence);
```

If we would **call the function**:

```
instring("Word", "Another Word");
```

it should have following return values:

- If the word would be found it would return the position it would've found the word at
- If the word wouldn't be found it would return -1

I can do it with the third parameter where I save the position, but unfortunately we are not allowed to use more than 2 parameters.

So the question is **how do I get it work?**
This is what I came up with so far:

```
int instring(char* word, char* sentence) {
    if (*word == '\0') {
        return 0;
    } else if (*word != '\0' && *sentence == '\0') {
        return -1;
    } else {
        if (*word == *sentence) {
            instring(word+1, sentence+1);
        } else {
            instring(word, sentence+1);
        }
    }
}
```

I get 0 if 'word' can be found otherwise i get -1. Since I can't store any values across function calls, I can't get the position where the 'word' string starts. **Is there any other way to get the position except for external variables and with only two input strings?**

Comment: When you call `instring()` recursively, you should `return` its result (to "pass" the value back up to the top).

Comment: @Cornstalks I did something like this: `return 1+instring(word, *(sentence));` but in the case where there is a string i just get the full length. Is that what you mean? I can't get my head around it…

Comment: @Kevin Ok, interesting. I had tried it with 'strlen' but it didn't work as i expected. Wouldn't my function call 'strlen' every time it gets executed?

Comment: Can you use loops inside of the body of the function? I can think of a simple way to do it that uses a loop and recursive calls...

Comment: @Cornstalks I've totally forgot everything except for recursion. I will try it, thanks.

Comment: What are the exact rules with regard to parameters and recursion? For example, can you use a helper function?

Comment: @DwayneTowell 1)Only two parameters are allowed( both strings ). 2)If 'word' can be found within 'sentence' final return value should be the position inside sentence( offset ) at which word was found. 3)If 'word' isn't part of the 'sentence' string it should return -1. 4)And as a hint I've got that I should consider every empty string as a part of any other string. I think that's all

Comment: I think you have to worry about your recursion scheme finding `"Word"` in `"Wrong parts of the data"`; when the scheme finds `W`, it will recurse looking for `"ord"` in `"rong parts of the data"`, and will find `o` after skipping over the `r`, and then find the `r` in `parts`, and the `d` in `data`.  So, you'd have to check that the return value from the recursive call is 0 before returning success.  You also have a problem with relaying the correct position for the match back to the calling function.

Comment: @orustammanapov, I understand the required return value, it's the other rules of the game/assignment which are somewhat ambiguous. For example, you could use a 3-parameter helper function that is recursive but which is called from the 2-parameter function required. If that is allowed the problem is easy again. Or, are the input string writable? Or can they be destroyed? Can you use a global variable? What about a static variable? We need to know the rest of the rules.

Comment: @DwayneTowell Unfortunately whether it be global, static or any other additional parameter - they all are not allowed. I had no problems writing a function with additional variables, but the only variable that is allowed is a local variable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are right, I've already rewrote my function probably at least 1000 times:) and instead of `if(*word==*sentence)` i had `if(*word==*sentence && *(word+1)==*(sentence+1))`. But this method has it's flaws either, for example i could be looking only for "W" instead of "Word", so my condition would only be true if my "W" I'm looking for is at the end so closing zeros('\0') would match. I think the best way would be if i find the first matching character to use loops as 'Cornstalks' suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int instring( char* word, char* sentence ){
    int lenw = strlen(word);
    int lens = strlen(sentence);
    if(lenw > lens) return -1;

    if(strncmp(sentence, word, lenw)==0)
        return 0;
    else {
        int ret = instring(word, sentence + 1);
        if(ret < 0)
            return ret;
        return 1 + ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't regard these as particularly elegant solutions, but then the problem is also not very elegant (the standard solution is iterative, and recursion is not optimal). Here is a pure recursive solution (no iteration) that is rather inefficient:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int const debug = 0;

static int instring(char const *word, char const *sentence)
{
  int rc;
  if (debug)
    printf("-->> [%s] in [%s]\n", word, sentence);
  if (*word == '\0')
    rc = 0;
  else if (*sentence == '\0')
    rc = -1;
  else if (*word != *sentence || (rc = instring(word+1, sentence+1)) != 0)
  {
    if ((rc = instring(word, sentence+1)) >= 0)
      rc++;
  }
  if (debug)
    printf("<<-- [%s] in [%s] = %d\n", word, sentence, rc);
  return rc;
}

int main(void)
{
  char word[] = "Word";
  char str1[] = "Another Word";
  char str2[] = "Wrong parts of the data";
  char str3[] = "A Word Or Two";

  printf("Search for [%s] in [%s] at offset %d\n",
         word, str1, instring(word, str1));
  printf("Search for [%s] in [%s] at offset %d\n",
         word, str2, instring(word, str2));
  printf("Search for [%s] in [%s] at offset %d\n",
         word, str3, instring(word, str3));
  return 0;
}
```

If you set `debug = 1;` you'll see why it is inefficient.  It uses the variable `rc` to simplify the debug tracing.

Here's an alternative that is more efficient because it uses iteration to limit the search when there's a match in the first character.  It is not hard to see how to remove what is left of the recursion (it is simple tail recursion) leaving a fully iterative solution, which is the normal way to solve this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int instring(char const *word, char const *sentence)
{
  int rc;
  if (*word == '\0')
    return 0;
  if (*sentence == '\0')
    return -1;
  if (*word == *sentence)
  {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; word[i] != '\0' && word[i] == sentence[i]; i++)
      ;
    if (word[i] == '\0')
      return 0;
  }
  if ((rc = instring(word, sentence+1)) >= 0)
    rc++;
  return rc;
}

int main(void)
{
  char word[] = "Word";
  char str1[] = "Another Word";
  char str2[] = "Wrong parts of the data";
  char str3[] = "A Word Or Two";

  printf("Search for [%s] in [%s] at offset %d\n",
         word, str1, instring(word, str1));
  printf("Search for [%s] in [%s] at offset %d\n",
         word, str2, instring(word, str2));
  printf("Search for [%s] in [%s] at offset %d\n",
         word, str3, instring(word, str3));
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Search for [Word] in [Another Word] at offset 8
Search for [Word] in [Wrong parts of the data] at offset -1
Search for [Word] in [A Word Or Two] at offset 2
```

The test code could be improved in both versions (by checking that the result is what is expected, and by using a test function rather than writing out so much code three times, and maybe by using a loop to scan through the test data.

Answer (score 0):

```
int len1 = strlen(word);
int len2 = strlen(sentence);
int n,k=0;

for(int i =0;i<len2;i++){
n =i;
  while(sentence[n] == word[k] && n<len2){
      if(k==len1 && ( n==len2 || sentence[n+1] ==' ')
        return i;//if word found return the position in the original string//
        n++;
        k++;
 }
k =0;
while(sentence[i] != ' ' && i<len2) //go to next word//
i++;
}
return -1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I have to use recursive functions.